# Update multiple HTML <div>'s from a JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to dynamically generate the homepage of my website by fetching the 10 most recent "posts" from the server. My question is if I have an HTML format like this

```
<div id="post1">
    <p id="link"> </p>
</div>
<div id="post2">
    <p id="link"> </p>
</div>
...
<div id="post10">
    <p id="link"> </p>
</div>
```

And a JSON object like this,

```
{"posts": [
      {
         "id": "randomId1",
         "link": "clickbait.com"
      } 
      { 
         "id": "randomId2",
         "link": "imgur.com"
      }
      { 
        ....
      }
      ]
     }
```

What is the best way to dynamically generate each div (and corresponding

child tag) using vanilla JS or jQuery . Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Might want to look at jQuery.parseJSON() then look over resulting object jquery appending $("#some_id").append("<div>with contents from object<.div>);

Comment: @yaje I'm pretty new to front end stuff, but when I populate my profile page I just write it to a element id.  But that is a lot easier because when I GET api/profile/1  there is only one result.  I tried to just assign 10 unique IDs to each elements placeholder tag (e.g. <a id=post1" >) and assign the first json element to that ID the second to the second, and so on, but it seems like a very cubersome strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this hope this is what you are trying to achieve.

```js
var posts = {
  "posts": [{
    "id": "randomId1",
    "link": "clickbait.com"
  }, {
    "id": "randomId2",
    "link": "imgur.com"
  }]
};

for (var i = 0; i < posts.posts.length; i++) {
    var html = '<div id="' + posts.posts[i].id + '"><p id="' + posts.posts[i].link + '"> HELLO </p></div>'
     $("#main").append(html)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a div that *will* contain all your 'generated' divs.

```
<div id="parentDiv">

</div>
```

Then, in code:

```
var yourJsonObject = {
...
};
var parentDiv = document.getElementById('parentDiv');
yourJsonObject.points.forEach(function(item, index){
        var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        newDiv.id = "post" + index;

        var pChild = document.createElement('p');
        pChild.id = "link";
        //if so required
        //replace above with 'pChild.id = item.link;'


        newDiv.appendChild(pChild);
        parentDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
    });
```